# Use Ocra To Make Installer With Argument

Tags: orca

I am trying to alter an MSI using Microsoft Orca to include a switch during install. To install this MSI using CMD you use the following line:

```
installer.msi LEGACY_MODE=1 /quiet
```

I am trying to add the LEGACY_MODE=1 to the msi with Orca. In the MSI on the InstallExecuteSequence  table on Orca is InstallLegacy and the Condition is (NOT REMOVE) AND LEGACY_MODE. Do I need to alter that condition to get this to work or add the switch somewhere else?